# Real life example to explain the Difference between Algebra and Arithmetic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Can anyone help me in finding out some real life examples to explain the difference between algebra and arithmetic ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think in real life you use arithmetic, not algebra :)

Comment: No you don't use anything :)

Comment: Perhaps you could lead us off. What do you think the difference between algebra and arithmetic is?

Comment: then why do we study algebra ?

Comment: Algebra is an extension of arithmetic ... but any example that clearly explains the concept to fresh minds @mixedmath

Comment: What is arithmetic? Is it computing $1+1=$? Algebra would be figuring out how to find $x$ from $x-1=1$?

Comment: it means from known facts to result is arithmetic & algebra is fro m result to find the unknown

Comment: To riff off @timur's comment: if you tell us what you think is the difference between the two, then maybe we have something to start with...

Comment: "it means from known facts to result is arithmetic & algebra is fro m result to find the unknown" - hmm, I don't know. Back in the day, some of the arithmetic problems we did involved questions like $5\times \text{\_} =15$ and $4 + \text{\_} =9$, and we kids were able to do them fine, even before we knew there was such a thing as algebra...

Comment: At least to me it seems difficult to guess the difference you intended to clarify. Algebra started with questions about solving polynomial equations but later it became general study of certain structures. To many people, arithmetic is just computing with numbers, but you will see it is understood somewhat differently for instance when you talk about arithmetics axioms.

Comment: Both "algebra" and "arithmetic" are *highly* overloaded terms. To properly answer your question, we need to know precisely what you mean by those terms. How much mathematics do you know?

Comment: if we say 2+2=4 then to write in general way would be a+b=c this is what algebra is ? @J.M

Comment: ax + b=c whats is its application in real life? @BillDubuque

Comment: Most of the mathematicians know the concepts themselves but don't have the skill to communicate and convince young minds , my question simply demands that ? @BillDubuque

Comment: @Hillbilli: Two questions have been asked of you (by Bill, J.M., and I) that you should answer: What do you mean by algebra and arithmetic? How much math do you know? If you continue to brush these questions aside, we will not be able to give you a good answer.

Comment: my question is so simple i want to explain the terms arithmetic & algebra to my students by giving real life example instead of going into complexities

Comment: What level of students?

Comment: @Hillbilli: I have now downvoted, and I wonder if this is a troll. I will be happy to remove my downvote if you explain what you mean by algebra and arithmetic, and explain the intended level of math.

Comment: @mixedmath : It is very obvious he is referring to elementary-school/junior-high-school algebra and arithmetic, and not 'abstract' algebra, or number theory, etc.  I don't know why everyone can't see that. He's a teacher trying to explain the importance of algebra and arithmetic to his students -- is there even a more common math question from the layman than this?

Comment: @Three, I was asking my question since I'm not so sure what OP wants. FWIW, I don't particularly consider the question "what do you subtract from $5$ to give $2$?" to be an algebra problem, for instance (though it can certainly be solved by the methods of algebra).

Comment: @Three: I have no idea where the line between middle-school/elementery-school algebra and arithmetic is. From my vantage point, I am inclined to believe that primary and secondary math education consists of teaching algorithms to solve abstract problem, all of which is arithmetic. But what I really don't understand is why the OP wouldn't just explain what he wants when we asked repeatedly.

Comment: @mixedmath Fair enough

Comment: A very simple question but i am sorry most of my friends came up with some very high order answers.this is where the fault lies...and poor minds start hating the subject

Comment: I don't think so. This question is one about how to name things, rather than a real knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

[A very famous book about algebra](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Al-jabr), the one that gave algebra its very name, was written around 1200 years ago by a Muslim mathematician called [al-Khwarizmi](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Muhammad_ibn_M%C5%ABs%C4%81_al-Khw%C4%81rizm%C4%AB). One of the types of real-life problems it treats extensively is that of calculating inheritances under the Islamic inheritance law of the time.

Here is one example from that book:

> A woman dies, leaving her husband, a son, and three daughters.

The implied question is: how is the woman's estate to be divided among the five heirs?

Under the law of the time, the husband is entitled to ¼ of the woman's estate, daughters to equal shares of the remainder, and sons to shares that are twice the daughters'. So a little *arithmetic* will suffice to solve this simple problem: We begin with the husband, who gets 25%. The son gets two shares and three daughters each get one share of the remaining 75%. That totals five shares, so each share is 75% ÷ 5 = 15%, and thus the son gets 30% and the daughters 15% each. No algebra was necessary, just direct calculation.

But a more complicated problem, also treated by al-Khwarizmi, goes like this:

> A man dies, leaving two sons and bequeathing one-third of his estate to a stranger. His estate consists of ten dirhams of ready cash and ten dirhams as a claim against one of the sons, to whom he has loaned the money.

The law in this case says that the stranger gets to collect his legacy before the shares of the rest of the estate is computed, and that if the debtor son's share of the estate is not large enough to enable him to pay back the debt completely, the remainder is written off as uncollectable.

Here arithmetic is not enough, because there is nowhere to begin.  We need to know the debtor son's share to calculate the amount of the writeoff. But we need to know the writeoff to calculate the total value of the estate, we need the value of the estate to calculate the bequest to the stranger, and we need to know the size of the bequest to calculate the size of the sons' shares.

The circularity makes this a problem in algebra rather than arithmetic, and we must solve it using algebraic technique: Let $e$ be the total value of the estate, $c$ be the amount of cash, $d$ be the debtor son's debt, $w$ the amount of the writeoff, $b$ be the bequest to the stranger, and $s$ be each son's share of the estate. Then we have:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
c & = & 10 \\
d & = & 10 \\
e & = & c + (d - w) \\
w & = & d - s \\
b & = & e / 3 \\
s & = & (e - b) / 2
\end{eqnarray}$$

We can solve these and find $w=5$, $e=15$, $b=5$, $s=5$, so 5 dirhams of the debt is written off, leaving an estate of 15 dirhams. The stranger gets one-third of this amount, 5 dirhams in cash, the non-debtor son gets the other 5 dirhams cash, and the debtor son's share is to have the remaining 5 dirhams of his debt forgiven.

I took these problems from  *Episodes in the Mathematics of Medieval Islam*, by J.L. Berggren (Springer, 1983).

Comment: So, elementary arithmetic is about the basic operations in maths that teach people how to combine the known quantities to derive the desired result.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JSG7AMGilM&feature=related...This is the link that also explains my question

Comment: Hillbilli, the place to explain your question is in your question, not in a comment on an answer. And a self-contained explanation trumps a call-out to YouTube.

Comment: @Hillbilli I'm not going to watch the video, but if you edit your question to explain further what you want to know, I'll try to answer.

Comment: Shouldn't the write-off be $w=\max\{0,d-s\}$?

Comment: @timur: Quite right. But in this case it's clear that there will have to be some amount written off, so we can simplify it.

Answer (score 5):

If you go the 20 miles from Pleasantville to Happytown at 20 miles per hour, and make the return journey at 10 miles per hour, what's your average speed? That's arithmetic.

If you go the 20 miles at 20 miles per hour, how fast do you have to make the return journey to have an average speed of 40 miles per hour? That's algebra.

Comment: +1. I think this answer is much more apt than mixedmath's high-powered one.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to give you an example of why we wanted clarification about what you meant by algebra and arithmetic, or the intended level of audience. So this is taking the opposite interpretation as Gerry, deliberately.

When I think of arithmetic, I think of my recent study of [A Course in Arithmetic](http://books.google.com/books/about/A_Course_in_Arithmetic.html?id=Ohj9NNk6btUC) by Serre. This serves as an excellent introduction to the idea of modular forms. What might be a real-world application of modular forms? Why, [black holes, of course](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4209). A little bit more down-to earth, we might mention that there are  [cryptosystems](http://modular.math.washington.edu/books/modform/modform/bibliography.html#elk98) that rely on modular forms.

When I think of algebra, I think of [Galois Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory) or [algebraic number theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_theory). A key example application of Galois Theory is that if we have a general quintic $ax^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + dx^2 + ed + f = 0$, we can't factor it with just addition, multiplication, and radicals. We care about factoring polynomials, just like we care about factoring numbers. I mention this because one of the most important and fundamental results of algebraic number theory is the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic). That's a bit of irony, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different kind of answer, which may or may not help, given the ambiguity of the question and the deep philosophical questions it raises (like "what is a number").

Arithmetic could roughly be described as working with the numbers we know within a particular system of numbers, and is often related in some way to working with things called integers (whole numbers) and fractions. These ideas are so useful that they've been generalised and abstracted by mathematicians many times - so there are 'integral domains' and 'rings of integers' and 'fields of fractions' and more to be learned about in due course.

Algebra might be roughly characterised as analysing the properties of mathematical systems which are in some way like numbers (things you can add or multiply) - though there are things there which we don't always think of as numbers like vector spaces and groups.

Roughly speaking we can use algebra to solve problems in arithmetic by putting our specific arithmetic problems in a more general algebraic context which gives more insight or options. So in elementary work we allow ourselves to use $x$ as an unknown number having the same basic properties as the numbers we know, and manipulate it as if it is a number until we find out what it must be. Solving polynomial equations we change our context to a 'splitting field' for the equation and analyse its properties, which gives us information about the roots.

This does not do proper justice to the terms, I think, because the distinction between algebra and arithmetic cannot be clearly made in this way (As others have suggested), but I hope it clarifies some ideas rather than clouding them.